How to get an image from database into < Image> in itext7?
In my invoiceGenerator i need to get an Image in the invoice that's stored in the postgres db as a byte[]
since i changed this image input from a local path hardcoded in method to an entity ImageDataFile in the database i have problems with itext7 recognising the file.
 try (ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
            PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(outputStream);

            PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(writer);
            pdfDocument.setDefaultPageSize(PageSize.A4);
            Document document = new Document(pdfDocument);

            float twocol1 = 280f;
            float[] twocolwidth1 = {twocol1, twocol1};
            float twocol = 200f;
            float[] twoColumnWidth = {twocol, twocol};


            ImageDataFile imageDataFileTopPage = imageRepos.findByName("goldencarrotImagekleinste.jpg")
                                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("image                       not found")); 

            ImageData imageTopPageData = ImageDataFactory.create(imageDataFileTopPage.getImageData());

            Image imageTopPage = new Image(imageTopPageData);
   

as a byte[] variable it also didn't work because the imageDataFactory.create from itext7 doesnt recognise the file.

"doesnt recognise the file." - Which error exactly do you get?

(1) Do not put them together for testing. (2) First test whether the image you took out is correct. Take out the image file from the Database (read the BLOB), and then save it to a directory to see if you can see the image correctly ( 3) If it is read correctly, you can proceed to the next step. (4) In addition, be careful whether the image originally saved in the database has a limited fixed format, whether it is only .png or it has png, jpg, gif, etc.

Here is the error:
com.itextpdf.io.IOException: Image format cannot be recognized.
at com.itextpdf.io.image.ImageDataFactory.createImageInstance(ImageDataFactory.java:582)
at com.itextpdf.io.image.ImageDataFactory.create(ImageDataFactory.java:82)

Hhmmm, that looks like the images are returned by ImageDataFile.getImageData() in some non-standard format. All image loading goes through the same image format recognition, whether given by path String, URL or byte array. The only different case are images loaded as awt images.

(1) Generally speaking, the image is taken out from the database and archived, like this (byte[] imageBytes = resultSet.getBytes("imageFiled");
try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/Downloads/xyz.jpg")) {
fos.write(imageBytes); ) Finally, check if xyz.jpg in the directory can be opened normally. (2) In your example, it seems that the image read from the database is this (imageRepos.findByName("goldencarrotImagekleinste.jpg")). It is recommended that you save the read image to a directory and check whether the image can be opened normally.

uhhh ohh my fault stupid, the first plan works now because i forgot the "!" sign in the while loop imageUtils.decompress. that declares why the byte[] wasn't recognised it was compressed....``
byte[] imageTopPageBytes = imageService.getImage("goldencarrotImagekleinste.jpg");
        ImageData imageTopPageData = ImageDataFactory.create(imageTopPageBytes);
        Image imageTopPage = new Image(imageTopPageData);


ImageService{

    public byte[] getImage(String name){

     ImageDataFile imageData = imageRepos.findByName(name).orElseThrow(() ->
                new ResourceNotFoundException("Image not found"));

     return ImageUtil.decompressImage(imageData.getImageData());
    }
}




ImageUtils{

    public static byte[] decompressImage(byte[] data) {
        Inflater inflater = new Inflater();
        inflater.setInput(data);

        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(data.length);

        byte[] tmp = new byte[4 * 1024];
        try {
            while (inflater.finished()) {   // <-- must be (!inflater.fisished())
                int count = inflater.inflate(tmp);
                outputStream.write(tmp, 0, count);
            }
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (DataFormatException | IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return outputStream.toByteArray();
    }

beginnersmistake haha forgive me guys any thanks
